# Unexpected output of Javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write a function that can perform permutation.

For example, if I input `[1, 2, 3]`, the expected answer will be

```
[ [ 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2, 1 ],[ 3, 2, 1 ],[ 3, 2, 1 ],[ 3, 2, 1 ],[ 3, 2, 1 ] ]
```

But instead of showing the answer, it returns `[[ ],[ ],[ ],[ ],[ ]]`

Any ideas?

```js
var permute = (nums) => {
    results = [];

    var backtrack = (nums, result) => {
        if (nums.length === result.length) {
            results.push(result);
        } else {

            for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                if (result.indexOf(nums[i]) > -1) {
                    continue;
                }
                result.push(nums[i]);
                backtrack(nums, result);
                result.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    backtrack(nums, []);
    return results;

};

console.log(permute([1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a local copy of `result` by slicing this array to prevent the same object reference in the result set.

```js
var permute = (nums) => {
    var results = [];
    var backtrack = (nums, result) => {
        if (nums.length === result.length) {
            results.push(result.slice());           // push copy
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                if (result.indexOf(nums[i]) > -1) {
                    continue;
                }
                result.push(nums[i]);
                backtrack(nums, result);
                result.pop();
            }
        }
    };
  
    backtrack(nums, []);
    return results;
};

console.log(permute([1, 2, 3]).map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

A version without pushing and popping.

```js
var permute = (nums) => {
    var results = [];
    var backtrack = (nums, result) => {
        if (nums.length === result.length) {
            results.push(result);
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                if (result.indexOf(nums[i]) > -1) {
                    continue;
                }
                backtrack(nums, result.concat(nums[i])); // use a new array
            }
        }
    };
  
    backtrack(nums, []);
    return results;
};

console.log(permute([1, 2, 3]).map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

Comment: Thanks! So this is due to object & array in js are pass by reference; therefore, the references in `results` become empty after the function is complete right ?

Comment: right. otoh you need this reference to manipulate with `push` and `pop`, but only inside of the actual function. it yould work if you replace `result.push(nums[i]);
                backtrack(nums, result);
                result.pop();` just with `backtrack(nums, result.concat(nums[i]));`

Comment: Wow, never thought of that. Thanks buddy ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Another approach using reverse(), an special case of permutation which OP gives as an example:

```
var arr = [ [ 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2, 1 ],[ 3, 2, 1 ],[ 3, 2, 1 ],[ 3, 2, 1 ],[ 3, 2, 1 ] ];

var permuted = arr.map((num) => {

    return num.reverse();

});

console.log(permuted);
```

Comment: how does reversing generate a permutation of the data?

Comment: The expected response given by OP is a reverse. It's an special case of permutation.